# How to remove DLLs(Assembly) from package from asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have a website. It has so many unnecessary DLLs in the Reference. It is also listed in `web.config`.

I want to remove unnecessary DLLs to speed up the start up time of the website. So, I have tried to removed 10 DLLs from Reference folder of the Solution explorer. Also removed all that assembly reference from `web.config`. I have removed all from `Bin` folder.

But whenever I run project for testing purpose, all that DLLs are automatically added in `web.config` and `bin`.

Can anybody please suggest me that how can I remove unnecessary DLLs from `web.config` and `bin`? So, it will not take time to load.

Comment: look for package.xml in the project, it may be because you are using nuget packages.

Comment: If you have ReSharper you could use `Remove unused References`

Comment: Maybe they are `nuget` references?...on the `nuget console` type: `Get-Package`

Comment: And remove the packages with `Uninstall-Package packageName`

Comment: @Hackerman All DLLs are of DevExpress. Can I do for DevExpress DLLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio goto Solution Exploter (Alt+Ctrl+L).
Expand References node and remove all what is to remove. It should resolve problem.

You need to remember that in bin folder are copied DLL required by all projects from solution, which you started project depends on. **So you need to check all dependents projects' references!**

If you use ReSharper you can use "Optimalize References".